# Electron vs Chromium: why one can access file system while the other can't?

Tags: javascript, electron, chromium

I'm looking into Electron and one thing stumps me. Since I know that you cannot access local file system from the browser in normal circumstances - extensions, etc. notwithstanding - how can Electron do that when it uses the Chromium Browser?

What am I missing? Does it not browserify the app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Electron also packages node, which has access to the File System.

Comment: That's true. But does it not run the app inside the browser? Does this mean that the Chromium Browser Electron uses is enhanced to include node and therefore is not a regular browser which doesn't support file system access by design?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_(software_framework) "_Node.js runtime for the backend and Chromium for the frontend_" There are plenty other online resources explaining how Electron works.

Comment: Got it! Thank you!